# What is the difference between a Container and Context in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

What is the difference between a Container and Context in Entity Framework and how they are related? I cannot find the explanation. Someone talks like they are the same. Someone talks about first or second, but never in compare. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below link.

**Container:**

An entity container is a logical grouping of entity sets, association sets, and function imports.

**Context:**

The Entity Framework enables you to query, insert, update, and delete data, using common language runtime (CLR) objects (known as entities). The Entity Framework maps the entities and relationships that are defined in your model to a database. The Entity Framework provides facilities to do the following: materialize data returned from the database as entity objects; track changes that were made to the objects; handle concurrency; propagate object changes back to the database; and bind objects to controls.

**[Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382821(v=vs.110).aspx)** **VS** **[Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx)**